# Открытие обзора файлов при клике на блок

Tags: jquery, html, html5, javascript

Нужно открыть выбор файлов в форме при клике на **div** или **button**.

**Заготовка:**

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="file" style="display: none;" name="file" />
  <button>Выбрать файлы</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вроде [работает](http://jsfiddle.net/yuSmP/418/):

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("input[type='file'").trigger('click');
});
```

**UPD:** нагуглил [вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/axelru/yuSmP/11/)

Comment: Не, это не то.

Answer (score 1):

Это не так просто, как может показаться.
У `input[type=file]` не вызывается событие `click()`.

Решение:
для `input[type=file]` задаётся огромный шрифт (200px, например), позиционируется этот элемент так, чтобы его кнопка оказалась строго над той кнопкой (внимание! проверять во всех браузерах на всех ОС. Эти элементы здорово отличаются), по нажатию на которую нужно вызывать окно выбора файлов. Свойством `clip` или `overflow:hidden` обрезается лишнее, сам `input[type=file]` делается полностью прозрачным.
Обманка, но работает.

Comment: Не вариант.

Comment: Ясное дело, что не вариант :)
Вот только этот не вариант работает исправно не в учебных примерах, а в реальных проектах.

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто объединить `input[type="file"]` и кнопку с помощью `label`, и скрыть `input`.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел статью [Styling & Customizing File Inputs the Smart Way](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/09/15/styling-customizing-file-inputs-smart-way/) может поможет в решении проблемы.

По сути сводится к тому что сказал [rip](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/193370/rip) кликаем на label, а input скрываем.